# updating the primary key and foreign key in multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I need to update the primary ID value of a record in table_1 and at the same time update the foreign keys referencing that ID value. In the sql below, i have included ALL the tables referencing table_1, however not all of these tables are referencing that particular record.
I am using the sql below:

```
UPDATE table_1 T1, 
table_2 T2, 
table_3 T3, 
table_4 T4,
table_5 T5, 
table_6 T6,
table_7 T7
SET T1.EMI_ID = 15678, 
    T2.AKN_EMI_FK = 15678, 
    T3.EXP_EMI_FK = 15678,
    T4.HDR_EMI_FK = 15678, 
    T5.LSU_EMI_FK = 15678,
    T6.MUT_EMI_FK = 15678, 
    T7.IMG_EMI_FK = 15678
WHERE T1.EMI_ID = 77777718765 AND 
T2.AKN_EMI_FK = T1.EMI_ID AND 
T3.EXP_EMI_FK = T1.EMI_ID AND 
T4.HDR_EMI_FK = T1.EMI_ID AND 
T5.LSU_EMI_FK = T1.EMI_ID AND 
T6.MUT_EMI_FK = T1.EMI_ID AND 
T7.IMG_EMI_FK = T1.EMI_ID;
```

It does not seem to be working and i believe that could be because in some tables that record id does not exist as foreign key.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using a foreign key UPDATE constraint:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (id INT NOT NULL,
                     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE child (id INT, parent_id INT,
                    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
                    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id)
                      ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```